# How do I add an explanatory footer in an android settings page?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I would like to add an explanatory footer in in the settings page for my Android app, looking like this example from the [Android Settings Guidelines](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/settings/settings-guidelines#footer):

[image]

Is there a way to do this using the androidx.preference library or do I need to build the settings screen from scratch by myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the androidx.preference library if you put the footer in the activity layout and then use a fragment for the preferences.

This is how I would do it:

1. In your SettingsActivity layout, put the footer at the bottom and a frame layout at the top, filling the rest of the screen (this frame layout will be the fragment container).
2. Create your preferences in a SettingsFragment and load the fragment from the activity.